# Problems with "+" in grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I'm trying to write a grep command to find lines like the below in a large text file:

```
<div class="node_thumbnail" data-type="file" name="GOPR0036.MP4_frame000001.jpg" data="813334c25191468c9f1c57afc99fde60" aid="133948" rel="/Files/ToolTipView?fileId=813334c25191468c9f1c57afc99fde60&pageNo=1&NoCache=101016083044" rev="topMiddle">
```

but the `+` symbol seems to be causing problems in the below commands:

```
 grep 'data=[a-z,0-9,\"]' file
```

Lots of hits

```
 grep 'data=[a-z,0-9,\"]+' file
```

No hits

Comment: A large HTML file, to be more specific ... [not that there's anything wrong with that ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348#answer-1732454)

Comment: just don't forget to take the habit of having: `LC_ALL="C" grep ...` instead of `grep ...` , so that [a-z] means always ascii letters a to z (ie, all lowercase ascii letters) instead of funny alternatives (ex: every letters except "Z", in some locales...)

Comment: and `[a-z,0-9,\"]` contains 2 occurence of ",", which is not necessary. you can have the same effect with `[a-z,0-9\"]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want `+` to mean "one or more of the preceding atom", then you have to do one of:

1. Use `-E` (Extended Regular Expressions) (or `-P`, PCRE):

   ```
   grep -E 'data=[a-z,0-9,\"]+' file
   ```
2. Escape `+` so that is treated specially in the Basic Regular Expressions used by default in `grep`:

   ```
   grep 'data=[a-z,0-9,"]\+' file
   ```

Comment: @MartinKS by the way, if all you want is the quoted string after `data=`, you could just run `grep -P 'data=".+?"` or, to get only the string and nothing else: `grep -oP '\bdata="\K[^"]+'`.

Comment: @MartinKS whoops, to get *only* the string, you need the `-o` option as well. I edited my previous comment. And you're welcome :)

Comment: @terdon, or just `sed -n 's/.*data="\([^"][^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file`, which is fully [POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).  (And `sed -nE 's/.*data="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file` will be POSIX compliant for the next edition of POSIX.)

Answer (score 9):

Points:

- `+` is an ERE (Extended Regular Expression) token, which indicates one or more of the preceding token, can be used if `-E` option of `grep` is used or with escaped `(\+`) in case of BRE (Basic Regex) i.e. only regular `grep`
- The character class `[a-z,0-9,\"]` would match any of the characters between `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `,` or `"`. This may not be what you want
- Normally `grep` outputs whole line, if you want to output only the matched portion, use `-o` option of `grep`

---

Based on your  example, you can do:

```
grep -E '\bdata=[a-z0-9"]+\b' file
```

- `-E` enables ERE
- `\b` matches string edges, zero width
- `data=` matches `data=` literally
- `[a-z0-9"]` matches any character of `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, and `"`. `+` matches the previous token one or more times

Your current pattern even you make it correct, without `\b` this would match false positives like `foo fdata=2322ab`, `data=12AB` and so on.

**Example:**

```
% grep -oE '\bdata=[a-z0-9"]+\b' <<<'<div class="node_thumbnail" data-type="file" name="GOPR0036.MP4_frame000001.jpg" data="813334c25191468c9f1c57afc99fde60" aid="133948" rel="/Files/ToolTipView?fileId=813334c25191468c9f1c57afc99fde60&pageNo=1&NoCache=101016083044" rev="topMiddle"'
data="813334c25191468c9f1c57afc99fde60
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use egrep:

```sh
egrep 'data=[a-z,0-9,\"]+' file
```

egrep is bundled with grep, it is just a wrapper for grep:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec grep -E "$@"
```

this is good for interactive use. However in scripts I would use `grep -E`.

Comment: Please don't recommend using `egrep`. It has been [deprecated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) in favor of `grep -E` for many years now. As the POSIX specs state, it is still supported and likely to be so for a while but the current POSIX (and GNU) `grep` has been designed to replace the older `egrep` and `fgrep` variants so it is better to use `grep -E` and `grep -f` instead.

Comment: egrep is fine for interactive use